# Time derivative, GLSL shader

Tags: glsl, shader

GLSL offers dFdx and dFdy, but why isn't there dFdt? Is it possible to get the color's rate of change, with respect to time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why isn't there dFdt?

Where would the `t` come from? `x` and `y` are based on the fragment's position in window space, relative to the neighboring fragments from the primitive being rendered. Fragments don't have a `t`.

Rendering is a 3-dimensional process, not 4-dimensional. Or at least, not 4-dimensional in that regard.

> Is it possible to get the color's rate of change, with respect to time?

It depends on what you mean by that. You can store the previous framebuffer and read from it to get the previous frame's color at that location. But that won't get you the *fragment's* rate of change. It will get you the framebuffer's rate of change.

After all, two fragments can overlap. Blending would cause the two colors to be combined. Depth testing would cause one to overwrite the other. So such a concept would only make sense if you compare the previous framebuffer image to the fully rendered current framebuffer image, not merely to a fragment during rendering.

Comment: Okay. I'm not sure how to play around with framebuffers though. By "t" i mean some uniform float that holds time.

Comment: @saldukoo: If it's `uniform`, the derivative will be *zero*.